# Gematria Matching

Tags: gematria-numerology

Using Gemtria for the purpose of determining whether two items have a relationship, are you allowed to match one method with another. For example, Absolute Value with Mispar Katan? Or AtBash with an AlBam? And so forth.

Comment: As a side point, I'm not sure "Using Gemtria for the purpose of determining whether two items have a relationship" works.

Comment: as @msh210 says, the worth of a relationship based on the gematria only is not great. There are variable degrees of relationship, for halacha e.g. or for a conceptual aspect, the use of Gematria is generally a supplement over  a previous background strongly build, by masoret of concepts

Comment: 100% correct. One cannot build theories on Gematriot; rather, he can only use them as supporting evidence of already existing theories/facts.

Comment: For example, we know that אונקלס translates the root word Moshach (and related words Moshiach, Mishcha, etc,) all the time throughout the Torah. It's לשון רבות as in Gedula/Gadlus. 
The Gematria of רבות? It's the same as משיח צדקנו..... which is the same also as דוד בן נצבת........
The gematria is 608. The Mispar Katan of that is actually דוד also (6+8=14)

Comment: So in these cases, all we are doing is substantiating existing facts.......

Comment: Reuben: If you want someone to see your response to their comment, you need to give them an `@` mention. I'm not sure if @msh210 saw your response.

Comment: No problem, Reuben. Happy to help :-)

Comment: @msh210; @Reuben Bakst As I like to say: Chazal say in Pirkei Avos "Gematrias are Parperara'os la'chachma," Gematrias are desserts to wisdom. If there is no wisdom, then there can be no dessert!"

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found your answer. The Tikunei Zohar explains that the concept of reduced value is related to the spiritual world of Yetzirah. On that basis, a **relationship can be established between these four forms of calculation**, the four spiritual realms, and the four letters of God’s name. I found this on [inner.org][1]

Comment: I do not understand this answer.

Comment: This comment from Tikkunei Zohar only establishes a relationship between small sum gematria and the universe of Yetzirah. It doesn't answer the question being asked. The OP is asking whether one can make relationships between words or phrases by using one system of gematria for one word and using a different system of gematria for a different word. That is an entirely different concept.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin You are correct. I did delete and write a new answer because I understood from sabbahillel that what I answered was not acceptable and I received a flag. And so I reread what I wrote and agreed that sabbahillel was correct in his flag of my answer and researched on the web what I answered here. (No hidden agenda here-emes)

Answer (score 0):

Your wording, if matching is "allowed", is puzzling if you mean the word literally, as in halachah, for why should you not be able to relate two cognitive ideas, even so much as to say they are irrelevant to each other, so I assume you mean if such matching can teach something, or has been used to teach something by our sages or rabbis. Certainly gematriot don't render halachic conclusions, for that would be absurd.

My answer would be, based on a natural Torah-based perspective, of a simple but observant and learning Jew, that of course such comparisons are permissible, for anything mind-related that Torah provides is fertile ground for further thought.

Answer (score 0):

Since gematria is an alphanumeric system, it is best used within a mathematical framework within which the results associated with the use of gematria must be consistent. The framework must necessarily include axioms from which we develop definitions, lemmas, theorems, and corollaries. Indeed, the Method of Gematria can be precisely defined as follows:

Let V_1 and V_2 be two verses in the Bible. Let N_1 be the total gematria of a set of words in V_1. Let N_2 be the total gematria of a set of words in V_2. It is possible that V_1 and V_2 are contextually or thematically linked if and only if N_1=N_2.

This definition refers to words or expressions in the verses that are contextual or thematic. By Collins English Dictionary, the context of a word, sentence, or text consists of the words, sentences, or text before and after it which help to make its meaning clear. So once the Method of the Gematria establishes the association (N_1=N_2) between the two verses, V_1 and V_2, then several verses before and after them may need to be consulted for a better understanding of the association. Also, by the same dictionary, in linguistics, the adjective thematic denotes a word that is the theme of a sentence. In grammar, it is of or relating to the stem or root of a word. Very often, there is a need to consult Strong’s Concordance and the Hebrew and Greek lexicons to fully understand the association between words that are thematic in the Bible.

I am happy to expound further.